# Entity Framework - Load entities with child entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, eager-loading

What I am trying is to load all the A entities in the database together with B entities. The relationship between them is Every A entitiy has one B entitiy.

The project I am working on has a repository pattern and it has an All() method as below.

```
    public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IObjectWithChangeTracker
        {
private IObjectSet<T> objectset;

        private IObjectSet<T> ObjectSet
        {
            get
            {
                if (objectset == null)
                {
                    objectset = UnitOfWork.Context.GetObjectSet<T>();
                }
                return objectset;
            }
        }
    public virtual IQueryable<T> All()
            {
                return ObjectSet.AsQueryable();
            }
    }
```

Is there any way that I can force B entities to eager load. What I've found is there there is no Include method on the IQueryable that returns from the All() method. I am happy to add a new member to repositroy so it can allow the client to use eager loading. But how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own extension method which will allow you to use `Include(path)` against any `IQueryable<T>`:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Include<TSource>
  (this IQueryable<TSource> source, string path)
{
  var objectQuery = source as ObjectQuery<TSource>;
  if (objectQuery != null)
  {
    return objectQuery.Include(path);
  }
  return source;
}
```

There's a full explanation on Julie Lerman's blog: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/agile-entity-framework-4-repository-part-5-iobjectset/

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `IQueryable` is agnostic of what's backing it, and `Include` is an Entity Framework feature. You could have an `IQueryable` that uses LINQ to Objects instead, and `Include` wouldn't make sense there. The easiest thing would be to change the type of `All()` to an `IObjectSet`, from which you should have access to an `Include` extension method.

If you can't change the return type of `All`, you will have to structure your queries in such a way that they pull in the child elements eagerly.

```
IList<Parent> parentsWithEagerLoadedChildren = parentRepo.All()
    .Select(p => new {p, p.Children}).ToList() // EF will attach the children to each parent
    .Select(p => p.p).ToList(); // Now that everything is loaded, select just the parents
```

Comment: Thanks your example worked and I am happy to report that it is sending one single query to get all the entitiy As and their Bs, which I was not expecting.

Comment: Regarding IObjectSet, I couldn't access to an include method. Then I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586351/ef4-linq-includestring-alternative-to-hard-coded-string which might be a better way to solve it