# Eagerly load an entity inside a LINQ query with EF 4.1 ObjectContext

Tags: .net, sql, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a bunch of entities in my EDMX and I set LazyLoading to `false`.
As I understand I now have to explicitly load realted entities with every query.
however most references I found point to `DbContext` and not `ObjectContext`.

And there seems to be great differences as how eager loading is done in code.
In my case I have Customers and Addresses in a 1:1 relationship.

How do I correctly load the address when fetching, e.g. customer #1488?

```
from c in context.Customers
where c.Id = 1488
select c;
```

Then I want to be able to use `c.Address.Street`, `c.Address.City` etc.

How do I load the Address(es)?

Comment: Is `Customers` and `Addresses` 1:1 oder 1:n (just because you mentioned "Address(es)"? In case it is 1:1, you might also consider changing the model so that `Customers` and `Addresses` are a single entity mapped to two tables.

Comment: One customer has 0 or 1 address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody else may give you a much more precise answer about `DbContext`. I generally work with `ObjectContext` where this code will do the job:

```
from c in context.Customers.Include("Addresses")
where c.Id = 1488
select c;
```

Comment: That actually seems work. Thanks. Is there any way to do this without writing a string? I'd have to update all string in case the Addresses entity changes its name. Is there not something like Entities.EntityNames.Addresses or so?

Comment: There's no out-of-the-box way, but have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586351/ef4-linq-includestring-alternative-to-hard-coded-string

Comment: @John: Hey, I came across this today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591934/how-to-include-subset-in-ef#comment12166241_9591985