# How to include subset in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I wrote a tiny function which return a generic IQueryable object.
Here is the code:

```
    public IQueryable<T> GetList<T>() where T : class
    {
        var result = dbContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        return result;
    }
```

I have a content table from the database. It has been converted into a content object. The content object has a related subset called State. How do I include it with my query?

Here is my current function:

```
    public IQueryable<Content> GetContentList()
    {
        var contentList = GetList<Content>();
        return contentList;
    }
```

It works, however, the State subset is not included. How can I include it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `CreateObjectSet<T>`. Don't you have a `ContentSet` to query with LINQ to Entities?

```
var result = dbContext.ContentSet.Include("States");
```

In my example the `Include` method is the one that explicitly includes your States.

Comment: Agreed that `.Include` is the way to go, but there's rarely a reason to not use the strongly-typed equivalent: `dbContext.ContentSet.Include(c => c.States)`.

Comment: @hvd: where is that defined?  All I see is the string version @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx

Comment: @JamesManning It's an extension method `System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions.Include`. I think it's available starting from EF4.1, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: @hvd: I never heard of this extension method, but I'm really glad if I don't have to use the string version anymore (+1 for the comment) :)